# Android preferences problem

Tags: android, preferences

I am following this tutorial: [link text](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:U2ENWxCHB20J:www.kaloer.com/android-preferences+android+preference+screen&cd=3&hl=hu&ct=clnk&gl=hu)

Preferences.java:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

}

PreferencesTutorial.java:

```
public class PreferencesTutorial extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button prefBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prefButton);
        prefBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                        Preferences.class);
                        startActivity(settingsActivity);
                }
        });
 }
```

}

Preferences.xml:
[image]

When application starts, and i click the prefButton, an error occures: "The application PreferencesTutorial (process PreferencesTutorial.com.examples) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

I haven't found any mistakes in the code.
I would also like to show my filestructure if that helps:
[image]

AndroidManifest.xml:
[image]

What is wrong with the code?

Even if i add (where the cursor is)

```
<activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="@string/set_preferences">
    </activity>
```

i still get the error.

Comment: What does the log say?  In eclipse, switch to the DDMS perspective to see logcat.  Or, run adb logcat from the command line.  You are probably missing the line in the manifest.

Comment: ...or run in debug mode, if you have Eclipse.

Comment: Debug mode is terrible. Use DDMS perspective. Or even better, run the logcat from the terminal.

Comment: debug mode and logcat are good for different things.  Its good to understand both tactics for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention this in your androidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="@string/set_preferences">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        </intent-filter>  
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this import, if you have it;

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have `Preferences` defined in your manifest.

However, as others have indicated, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and see the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: I updated the post with androidmanifest.xml. Seems fine to me...
Logcat says: Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit Activity class {PreferencesTutorial.com.examples/java.util.prefs.Preferences}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: When i start the app, i got a nullpointer exception:
[2011-01-19 10:38:06 - ddms]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:670)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

Comment: I don't what was the problem, but i did the tutorial twice again and both of them are working, but for this one. I compared the files, and haven't found any differences. Maybe a bug. Or maybe i am the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error raised in the OnClick in PreferencesTutorial Class or onCreate in the preferences Class? Stick a couple of Log.d("Debug","%ID") in various locations and see which one doesn't get called.